# Crashlytics native crash symbols for multiple modules

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric, twitter-fabric

I was hoping to find some additional information about the mechanics of the symbol upload. Specifically, symbol upload for multi-module projects.

Suppose I have a project with the following structure with external native dependencies:

```
- library_1
  - jniLibs
    - lib1.so
- library_2
  - jniLibs
    - lib2.so
- app
```

The entry point is the `app` module, which contains the `build.gradle` file.

The first question is, can I independently run the symbols upload gradle task on each of the modules via the `crashlytics {}` gradle DSL? I.e by swapping out the relative paths to the `androidNdkOut`, `androidNdkLibsOut`, `manifestPath`?

The second question is, are uploaded symbols overwritten on every task run? I.e if I run symbols upload on `lib1.so` and then on `lib2.so` are the symbols for `lib1.so` removed?

Finally, where can I view the symbols that have been uploaded?

Comment: Hi @Karn! Matt here from the Crashlytics team. Quick question - do you have debug symbols for these libraries?

Comment: Hey @mWillis, I'm not quite sure I understand your followup question. Are the symbols available through the external library (`.so`) or do I have to generate them at the time of build?

Comment: To clarify, for any `.so`, you'll need both the production copy (with no symbols) and a matching copy with debugging symbols included inside the `.so` (more information on that can be found here: https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/ndk.html#specifying-the-path-to-debug-and-release-binaries). Do you have the `.so`s with debugging symbols?

Comment: Did anyone find a solid solution for this?